# Applying Styling to Dynamic XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSL stuff
 Created an XML and its contents can be dynamic i.e. in some cases some of elements may not be present and I want to output it as HTML table , how can I write such an XSL ?

Sample XML , in some cases Configuration Element may not be present entirely ,

```
    <Stat>
         <Name></Name>
         <Hardware></Hardware>
         <Software></Version>
         <Version></Version>
         <State></State>
    </Stat>
    <Configuration>
     <Up>
        <Option1>2000</Option1>
        <Option2>2500000</Option2>
        <Option3>0</Option3>
        <Option4>0</Option4>
        <Option5>NA</Option5>
     </Uplink>
     <Down>
        <Option1>2000</Option1>
        <Option2>2500000</Option2>
        <Option3>0</Option3>
        <Option4>0</Option4>
        <Option5>NA</Option5>
      </Down>
   </Configuration>
```

Expected Output:
HTML table with row and col span , 
does some kind of recursive solution possible which automatically goes to each XML elemnt and put it in table header and picking corrsponding value ?
[image]

Comment: "*Expected Output: HTML table with row and col span*" I am afraid that's not specific enough; please post **the actual code** you expect to see as the result.

Comment: Added expected output picture...not exact , some columns missing..but this is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML was well formed, and had a root element, the sort of thing you would for your headers would be like this

```
 <th colspan="{count(Stat/*)}">
     <xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
         <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
</th>
```

This outputs the header cell for the "Stat" heading. Note the use of "Attribute Value Templates" in doing the colspan. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

The **xsl:if** tests if Configuration items exist, and if so adds the rowspan.

Similarly, the heading for "Configuration" would be like so

```
<xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
   <th colspan="{count(Configuration/*/*)}">
       <xsl:text>Configuration</xsl:text>
   </th>
</xsl:if>
```

For the header row containing "UP" and "DOWN" you can iterate over the child elements of Configuration

```
<tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="Configuration/*">
       <th colspan="{count(*)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
       </th>
   </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Doing the next row, would simply involve select the child elements of "Stat" and the grand-children of "Configuration"

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="header" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="header" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="{count(Stat/*)}">
               <xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
                  <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
               </xsl:if>
            </th>
            <xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
               <th colspan="{count(Configuration/*/*)}">
                  <xsl:text>Configuration</xsl:text>
               </th>
            </xsl:if>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <xsl:for-each select="Configuration/*">
                <th colspan="{count(*)}">
                   <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                </th>
             </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="header" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="header" />
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="row" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="row" />
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
      <th>
         <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      </th>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<root>
    <Stat>
         <Name>A</Name>
         <Hardware></Hardware>
         <Software></Software>
         <Version></Version>
         <State></State>
    </Stat>
    <Configuration>
     <Up>
        <Option1>2000</Option1>
        <Option2>2500000</Option2>
        <Option3>0</Option3>
        <Option4>0</Option4>
        <Option5>NA</Option5>
     </Up>
     <Down>
        <Option1>2000</Option1>
        <Option2>2500000</Option2>
        <Option3>0</Option3>
        <Option4>0</Option4>
        <Option5>NA</Option5>
      </Down>
   </Configuration>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5" rowspan="2">Stat</th>
    <th colspan="10">Configuration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Up</th>
    <th colspan="5">Down</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Hardware</th>
    <th>Software</th>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Option1</th>
    <th>Option2</th>
    <th>Option3</th>
    <th>Option4</th>
    <th>Option5</th>
    <th>Option1</th>
    <th>Option2</th>
    <th>Option3</th>
    <th>Option4</th>
    <th>Option5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much let me try !

Comment: Wanted to ask whats the use of second xsl:template block ? in second template block you are trying to access  th which is closed by previous template block...code is working just wanted to understand thanks

Comment: The second template isn't trying to access the `th` in the previous block. Templates only match against the input XML document, not the output document. The thing to note is the use of "mode" on the two templates (and the associated `xsl:apply-templates`). The templates are matching the same elements in the input XML but do two different things, depending on the node. One outputs the header cells with the element name, the other outputs the cells with the actual value.

Comment: Thanks I got the point, another question I have is: suppose I have multiple of Stat and Configuration element , how can I create a table with just one table header and multiple data rows ? I tried something like this : xsl temple matching / which will create html and then it should call another template to construct table header and then table data..  Problem is coming while constructing table header because it should take only instance of Stat and Configuration and calcukate colspan and rowspan etc , currenlty if I say Stat/* , it select all the Stat block in xml and give the count , Help

Comment: It's probably best if you ask a whole new question for this. If you should a sample of the XML with multiple Stat elements, along with what you have tried, it probably won't take much to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573245/html-table-header-from-xml-element   have a look , and suggest whats wrong thanks