# HTML table header from XML element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a sample XML and I wanted to convert it to HTML Table but the table header should come from XML elements , 
example:

Have a look at attached xml and xsl, something I am missing (I am new to XML world , now to showcase some of data so I have to output data in XML, and XML looks better when styled and hence all this exercise)

```
<root>
<Device>
<Stat>
     <Name>A</Name>
     <Hardware>B</Hardware>
     <Software>C</Software>
     <Version>D</Version>
     <State>E</State>
</Stat>
<Configuration>
 <Up>
    <Option1>2000</Option1>
    <Option2>2500000</Option2>
    <Option3>0</Option3>
    <Option4>0</Option4>
    <Option5>NA</Option5>
 </Up>
 <Down>
    <Option1>2000</Option1>
    <Option2>2500000</Option2>
    <Option3>0</Option3>
    <Option4>0</Option4>
    <Option5>NA</Option5>
  </Down>
</Configuration>
</Device>
<Device>
<Stat>
     <Name>e</Name>
     <Hardware>f</Hardware>
     <Software>g</Software>
     <Version>h</Version>
     <State>i</State>
</Stat>
<Configuration>
<Up>
    <Option1>2000</Option1>
    <Option2>2500000</Option2>
    <Option3>0</Option3>
    <Option4>0</Option4>
    <Option5>NA</Option5>
 </Up>
 <Down>
    <Option1>2000</Option1>
    <Option2>2500000</Option2>
    <Option3>0</Option3>
    <Option4>0</Option4>
    <Option5>NA</Option5>
  </Down>
</Configuration>
</Device>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
            <table border="1">
                 <xsl:call-template name="tablesetup" />

        <xsl:apply-templates />

        </table>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name ="tablesetup">

     <tr>
        <th colspan="{count(/root/Stat/*)}">
           <xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
              <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>

           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
        </th>
        <xsl:if test="/root/Configuration[*]">
           <th colspan="{count(/root/Configuration/*/*)}">
              <xsl:text>Configuration</xsl:text>
           </th>
        </xsl:if>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="/root/Configuration/*">
            <th colspan="{count(*)}">
               <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            </th>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Stat/*" mode="header" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Configuration/*/*" mode="header" />
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Stat/*" mode="row" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Configuration/*/*" mode="row" />
     </tr>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
  <th>
     <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
  </th>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:
[image]

Header should look like this and then in next 2 rows table data should follow since we have 2 'Device' element

Comment: Would it be possible to show the HTML you expect to be output in this case too? Thanks!

Comment: Headers should be like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8gNr.png and then in each row data should follow ,

Comment: Ideally, you should edit your question with the actual HTML code you expect. In particular with the row data actually present. That way, there is no misunderstanding about what you expect. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for confusion..I have updated the question with expected output

Answer (score 0):

For you header cells, instead of doing as currently

```
    <th colspan="{count(/root/Stat/*)}">
       <xsl:if test="Configuration[*]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>

       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
    </th>
```

You need to adjust this to only check the first Stat and Configuration cells

```
    <th colspan="{count(/root/Device[1]/Stat/*)}">
       <xsl:if test="/root/Device[1]/Configuration[*]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
    </th>
```

This assumes all the **Stat** and **Configuration** elements have the same structure. (Otherwise it become much harder)

For the rows, currently it does

```
 <tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="row" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="row" />
 </tr>
```

Instead, replace it with a line to select individual **Device** elements, which correspond to your rows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Device" />
```

And then it is in the template that matches **Device** where you output the row data

```
<xsl:template match="Device">
     <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="row" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="row" />
     </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
            <table border="1">
                 <xsl:apply-templates name="root" />
       </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
     <tr>
        <th colspan="{count(Device[1]/Stat/*)}">
           <xsl:if test="Device[1]/Configuration[*]">
              <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">2</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:text>Stat</xsl:text>
        </th>
        <xsl:if test="Device[1]/Configuration[*]">
           <th colspan="{count(Device[1]/Configuration/*/*)}">
              <xsl:text>Configuration</xsl:text>
           </th>
        </xsl:if>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="Device[1]/Configuration/*">
            <th colspan="{count(*)}">
               <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            </th>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Device[1]/Stat/*" mode="header" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Device[1]/Configuration/*/*" mode="header" />
     </tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Device" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
  <th>
     <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
  </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Device">
     <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Stat/*" mode="row" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration/*/*" mode="row" />
     </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5" rowspan="2">Stat</th>
    <th colspan="10">Configuration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Up</th>
    <th colspan="5">Down</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Hardware</th>
    <th>Software</th>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Option1</th>
    <th>Option2</th>
    <th>Option3</th>
    <th>Option4</th>
    <th>Option5</th>
    <th>Option1</th>
    <th>Option2</th>
    <th>Option3</th>
    <th>Option4</th>
    <th>Option5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>2500000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>NA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: some this w3c page is not display with the xslt you gave http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: Ah! This was because you had edited the XML to add a "Device" element. I have changed my answer to cope with this.